# How to check in a file into TFS using Java SDK

Tags: java, tfs

I am planning to integrate the TFS with another application using websevice.
I am new to TFS.so I downloaded the TFS Java SDK 2010.I have been writing s sample program to checkin file into TFS. but not successful.  On internet also not much helpful post for Java side SDK samples.

Below is the code I have written:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = SnippetSettings.connectToTFS(); //got the connection to TFS
    VersionControlClient vcc = tpc.getVersionControlClient();
    //WorkspaceInfo wi = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    //vcc.get
    String[] paths =new String[1];

    paths[0]="D:\\Tools\testfile.txt"; //wants to checkin this local file 


    Workspace ws = vcc.createWorkspace(null,"Testworkspacename3", null, "","Testcomment",null, null);  // this is workspace created at path local C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces


    int item = ws.pendAdd(paths, true, null, LockLevel.NONE,  GetOptions.GET_ALL,  PendChangesOptions.GET_LATEST_ON_CHECKOUT); // this line gives me 0 count. so this is problematic . 0 means nothing is being added.
    PendingSet pd = ws.getPendingChanges();  

    PendingChange[] pendingChanges = pd.getPendingChanges();
    ws.checkIn(pendingChanges, "samashti comment");


    Project project = tpc.getWorkItemClient().getProjects().get(SnippetSettings.PROJECT_NAME);
    System.out.println();
```

Please help here...what is the wrong here. Can some one provide me correct working sample for new file checkin and existing file checkin using JAVA.

Comment: Did you get any  error ?

Comment: You need to map the folder d:\tools in your workspace before you can add files in that folder to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer these steps below:

1. Connect to team project collection
2. Get version control client
3. Create a new workspace
4. Add file to workspace
5. Get pending changes
6. Check in pending changes

Below are some links about TFS SDK for JAVA for your reference:

- https://github.com/gocd/gocd/blob/master/tfs-impl/src/com/thoughtworks/go/tfssdk/TfsSDKCommand.java
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/tfs/commands/NewWorkspaceCommand.java

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code snippet for creating and mapping workspace as per TFS-SDK-14.0.3

```
    public static Workspace createAndMapWorkspace(final TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc) {
    final String workspaceName = "SampleVCWorkspace" + System.currentTimeMillis(); //$NON-NLS-1$
    Workspace workspace = null;

    // Get the workspace
    workspace = tpc.getVersionControlClient().tryGetWorkspace(ConsoleSettings.MAPPING_LOCAL_PATH);

    // Create and map the workspace if it does not exist
    if (workspace == null) {
        workspace = tpc.getVersionControlClient().createWorkspace(
            null,
            workspaceName,
            "Sample workspace comment", //$NON-NLS-1$
            WorkspaceLocation.SERVER,
            null,
            WorkspacePermissionProfile.getPrivateProfile());

        // Map the workspace
        final WorkingFolder workingFolder = new WorkingFolder(
            ConsoleSettings.MAPPING_SERVER_PATH,
            LocalPath.canonicalize(ConsoleSettings.MAPPING_LOCAL_PATH));
        workspace.createWorkingFolder(workingFolder);
    }

    System.out.println("Workspace '" + workspaceName + "' now exists and is mapped"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

    return workspace;
}
```